# Locating and adding state layers to a QGIS map

Tags: qgis, layers, united-states, mapping, thematic-map

If I wanted to add layers for a state (Indiana) in a program like QGIS so I could produce several maps (Infrastructure, Water Resources, Mineral Resources, and HAZMAT concerns), how would I locate and integrate that state's layer data for each type of layer. For example, on an infrastructure map, I need to identify airports, cemeteries, hospitals, recreational facilities, religious facilities, schools, managed lands, pipelines, railroads, trails, county boundaries, interstates, and local roads all on one aerial view.

Comment: Do you have any of those layers that you need? Also, are you looking for a website to download the data?

Comment: No, I don't. I'd need to figure out how to integrate each layer into the program, but I'd like to make it a static resource in the program so I don't have to download it section by section each time. I was able to find this http://maps.indiana.edu/layerGallery.html?category=Airports as a website with resources, but I'm afraid this technology is a bit beyond me right now. 

I'm just an ecologist with zero cartography experience.

Comment: There are many options that may work best for your situation. It's up to you on how much you want to delve into using this approach or similar tools.

Answer (score 2):

The general process you will employ whenever you are making a map, will be acquire the data (e.g. shapefile), use GIS software (QGIS). Once you have those two, you could add your shapefiles to QGIS and layer the data as you see fit to compose the map of to fulfill your need.